# XspCommandButton event Handling AktionListener or XspEventHandler

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

i am currently working on an xsp library component that contains a `XspInputText` field a `XspCommandButton`, and some custom html Code created with the `ResponseWriter`.

I am able to render every thing korrekt but now i am stuck with the question how to add a EventHandler to my Button.

As far i could see i have two posibilities add a `XspEventHandler` to the Page or try using the `addActionListener` of the `XspCommandButton`.

I have already tried both without any luck with the event listener i get stuck with the `onClick` event and with the `XspEventHandler` i cant find anything how to trigger one of Methods of my Component. I have searched the internet but i found nothing on this topic.

I took a look in one of my XPage Codes in /xsp/ComponentName.., there the designer uses the .setScript method to add a script via

```
MethodBinding script = evaluator.createMethodBinding(result,
```

but i think that will not work in my example.

Here is a sample of my Code:

```
public class myComponentRenderer extends Renderer{

public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {

        XspDiv div = createSearchDiv(context,control.getTypeAheadList());
        div.encodeBegin(context);
        div.encodeChildren(context);
        div.encodeEnd(context);

}

private XspDiv createUpperDiv(FacesContext context,ArrayList<String> typeAheadList) throws IOException{
        XspDiv container = new XspDiv();
        container.setId("container");

        XspInputText SearchInput = new XspInputText();
        SearchInput.setId("input");
        SearchInput.setRole("textbox");
        SearchInput.setStyleClass("lotusText");
        SearchInput.setType("text");

        XspTypeAhead searchTypeAhead = new XspTypeAhead();
        searchTypeAhead.setIgnoreCase(true);
        searchTypeAhead.setMode("partial");
        searchTypeAhead.setVar("typed");
        searchTypeAhead.setValueMarkup(true);
        searchTypeAhead.setMinChars(1);
        searchTypeAhead.setValueList(typeAheadList);

        XspCommandButton searchButton = new XspCommandButton();
        searchButton.setId("searchBtn");
        searchButton.addActionListener(/* ? new AktionListener(...)*/);

        //or
```

**Update:**
I updated my Code after the Comment from Sven Hasselbach, now I am able to do a full refresh of the page, but the Code i try to pass through the `MethodeBinding` does not get Executed. I dont recive any errors or messages, just the "big nothing happens".

```
XspEventHandler searchEvent = new XspEventHandler();        
    MethodBinding action = context.getApplication().createMethodBinding("#{javascript:print(\"Hallo World\");}",
            null);

    searchEvent.setAction(action);
    searchEvent.setSubmit(true);
    searchEvent.setEvent("onclick");
    searchEvent.setRefreshMode("complete");

        searchButton.getChildren().add(searchEvent);


            container.getChildren().add(searchTypeAhead);       
            container.getChildren().add(SearchInput);
            container.getChildren().add(searchButton);


    }
```

My knowledge on ActionListeneris also a bit limited but i am pretty sure i cannot compare these `ActionListener` to the one used in the AWT.

**Update2:**

I found another interesting thing that maby explains why my script does not get executed. When i take a look at the Client Side HTML Code of my comonents i can see that they dont get any computed id's like the rest of my XPage.

My Component: `<div id="myComponentHolder1">`

Other XPage Components: `<span id="view:_id1:myComponent1">`

**Solved:**

Finally working. Thanks alot Sven for the hint with the Method Binding. It works now but i had to move the `createUpperDiv` Method from my `Renderer` to my `Component`. Also i had to change the Component: to `implement` the `FacesComponent` then i added the Method to the `buildContents` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your method binding from the application instance and attach it to your button.
Here is an example XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:button
        value="Add Event"
        id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                var event = new com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler();
                var code = "#{javascript:print(\"Hello World!\")}"
                var action = facesContext.getApplication().createMethodBinding( code, null );

                event.setAction(action);
                event.setSubmit(true);
                event.setEvent("onclick");
                event.setRefreshMode("complete");

                var cmp = getComponent("button2");
                cmp.getChildren().add( event );

            }]]>
            </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
    &#160;
    <xp:button
        value="Exec Event"
        id="button2">
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Clicking the *Add Event* button creates a new event and attaches it to the *Exec Event* button.

Maybe this can help you.

Comment: Thanks.. nice.. i am able to do a full refresh now. However the print is lost.. and creates a Servlet error in the Server Console (i will try some other code). I will do some try's on that then post a update to my question.